# Limit request size to Web applications

Tags: c, web-services, cgi

This is a question regarding basic understanding of a web application.

Although c is poor choice for web application, It is easier for me to ask this question as it relates to C CGI.

In C CGI, when a request comes in, what prevents a malicious user from sending a huge input size for one of the parameters? Is it possible to drop such a request even before evaluating the size inside of a program?

Does this happen at the web server level where we can say drop certain request if it is beyond a certain size? If the size of the request parameter is determined using the argv, where does the space get allocated?

In other words, How can we prevent a web application from processing malicious request of big size so the web application does not even allocate space or spend processing.

Thanks,

Kg

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You can choose to only read a limited amount of a request in any language, and cgi isn't really relevant to this at all.

Comment: @JimB Changed the post to ask only one question. Your comments says I can choose to only read only a limited amount of a request. I want to know how to "choose" it. Is it a setting at the server level or a web app level. An example would be awesome.

Comment: @KartDev: Thanks. I updated the tags for you to also match, and to remove the tags from the title.

Comment: Why specifically CGI, which is all but dead? You can read exactly how it works in the relevant [spec, RFC-3875](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875). It could be limited by the server _or_ the CGI program, and is entirely implementation specific.

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. Please learn [ask].

Comment: Hi @Olaf, I did not ask to be tutored.Ohers had comments and I rectified my question based on their comments. I am no way perfect. You could have simply pointed me to the link without the unwanted comment about tutoring..and act condescending. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @KartDev: Accusing someone to be condescending is quite insulting. It is **you** asking an off-topic question. Users are expected to follow the rules.

Comment: In general, with CGI and similar technologies, the webserver will buffer request data before invoking the service program or script. So, in most cases, problems with over-large requests need to be tackled in the webserver, not the CGI program. Most (all?) webservers have limits on the amount of data that can be accepted from the various (GET, POST) request types, and these limits can usually be modified. The documentation for your specific webserver should cover these topics. If not, perhaps try a forum for sysadmin issues?

Comment: @KevinBoone, Thanks a lot! This was the answer/ direction I was looking for.I did read the webserver had to "dechunk" the data before feeding to a cgi program and I could set the dechunk size on the server. However I wanted to be sure. Thanks again. If you have this as an answer, I can close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, with CGI and similar technologies, the webserver will buffer request data before invoking the service program or script. So, in most cases, problems with over-large requests need to be tackled in the webserver, not the CGI program. Most (all?) webservers have limits on the amount of data that can be accepted from the various (GET, POST) request types, and these limits can usually be modified. The documentation for your specific webserver should cover these topics.